# Yii2 and sqldataprovider in inner query, write one aggregating expression per reporting column, 2. In an outer query, build the horizontal sums

Tags: yii2, pivot-table

I'm trying to make an Pivot Table from rows to columns using Yii2 and I have the following table in Mysql:

CREATE TABLE Sales (empID INT, yr SMALLINT, sales DECIMAL(10,2)); 
INSERT sales VALUES 
(1, 2005, 12000),(1, 2006, 18000),(1, 2007, 25000), 
(2, 2005, 15000),(2, 2006, 6000),(3, 2006, 20000),(3, 2007, 24000);

and the following sqldataprovider in Yii2:
[image: sqldataprovider in yii2]

and the final table view showing only the sums and not showing sums per year:
[image: final view of generated table not showing sums per year]

Comment: Please check the answer in the following blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following blog about yii2.
[Yii2 and Pivot Tables](http://yii2ideas.blogspot.al/2015/12/array-of-database-result-to-mannually.html?showComment=1460714292388#c5111430717508774521)
Thanks to SHANEESH P PALLIYALIL, he has been very halpful.